# How can I stop adware affecting my site?

Tags: advertising, malware

We have just started running our own ads on our site but are now getting bombarded with complaints from users that "Russian Bride" ads are showing up **below** our ads.

We know this is caused by AdWare like the Ask tool bar etc.

My question is, does any one know how to stop the AdWare from affecting our site?

Comment: The Ask Toolbar is a client add-on and you have no control over it.  Are you sure that's what is happening or do you think your site has been hacked and code is being injected?

Comment: It is definitely the Ask toolbar (among others) What I'm wondering is if there is a way of intercepting the client side code injection (or what ever the toolbar is doing) using jQuery or something?

Comment: You have no control over their browser or tool-bars and no actual way of detecting their add-ons so scripts wont help. Change your ad coding so the toolbars cant detect it

Answer (score 1):

If the Russian brides ads are being added through a client-side addin then there is no way to prevent it unfortunately. The only thing you can do is when you get told by website users that the ad is showing up inform them that it is to do with the addin they have and advise them on the process  to remove it from their browser.